# No evaluator found. Use `DefaultTrainer.test(evaluators=)`, or implement its `build_evaluator` method

Tags: python, resnet, detectron, imagedata, mask-rcnn

I am using Detectron2 in a notebook and I keep getting the error: **No evaluator found. Use `DefaultTrainer.test(evaluators=)`, or implement its `build_evaluator` method.**

I already have the **build_evaluator** function in the **Trainer** function.

```py
class AugTrainer(DefaultTrainer):
    @classmethod
    def build_evaluator(cls, cfg, dataset_name, output_folder=None):
        return COCOEvaluator(dataset_name, output_dir=output_folder)
    
    @classmethod
    def build_train_loader(cls, cfg):
        return build_detection_train_loader(cfg, mapper=custom_mapper)
```

**Trainer** gets called here:

```py
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg) if not is_augment else AugTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=is_resume_training)
trainer.train()
```

I thought **COCOEvaluator** would also get called when the **Trainer** gets called.

```py
print("### EVALUATING ON VALIDATION DATA ####")
# trained model weights
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = str(MODEL_PATH)
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.6   # set a custom testing threshold

cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 64

evaluator = COCOEvaluator(DATA_REGISTER_VALID, cfg, False, output_dir=cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, use_fast_impl=True)

val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, DATA_REGISTER_VALID)

results = inference_on_dataset(trainer.model, val_loader, evaluator=evaluator)
    
# print the evaluation results
print("Evaluation results for dataset {}: \n".format(DATA_REGISTER_VALID))
print("Average Precision (AP) in given IoU threshold: \n")
print(results["bbox"])
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

I've tried following these methods:

- https://gist.github.com/ortegatron/c0dad15e49c2b74de8bb09a5615d9f6b#file-mytrainer-py
- https://eidos-ai.medium.com/training-on-detectron2-with-a-validation-set-and-plot-loss-on-it-to-avoid-overfitting-6449418fbf4e
- [https://kilong31442.medium.com/colab-note-how-to-train-detectron2-on-custom-objects-3974be195dd8#:~:text=Train%20Custom%20Detectron2%20Detector](https://kilong31442.medium.com/colab-note-how-to-train-detectron2-on-custom-objects-3974be195dd8#:%7E:text=Train%20Custom%20Detectron2%20Detector)

I want the evaluator to print Average Precision (AP) and Evaluation results for dataset

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would like to perform evaluation during the training process instead of after the training process. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Define a CocoTrainer class that includes the evaluator:

```
class CocoTrainer(DefaultTrainer):
    @classmethod
    def build_evaluator(cls, cfg, dataset_name, output_folder=None):
        if output_folder is None:
            os.makedirs("coco_eval", exist_ok=True)
            output_folder = "coco_eval"
        return COCOEvaluator(dataset_name, cfg, False, output_folder)
```

2. Set the model configurations for training:

```
from detectron2.evaluation import COCOEvaluator
# Import required libraries

cfg = get_cfg() # obtain detectron2's default config
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x.yaml"))
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("train",) # training set
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("val",) # validation set
cfg.TEST.EVAL_PERIOD = 100 # do evaluation once after 100 iterations on the cfg.DATASETS.TEST (Validation set)
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x.yaml") # Let training initialize from the model zoo
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.0005 # pick a good LR, 0.00025 or 0.0005 seems like a good start
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 4
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 4 # this is the real "batch size"
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = (500) # 500 or 1000 iterations are a good start; for better accuracy, increase this value or comment the line to use the default value in cfg (90000)
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 16 # (default: 512), select smaller if faster training is needed
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = len(classes)
cfg.OUTPUT_DIR = "your/output/dir"
```

3. Save the configurations:

```
import yaml
with open("your/output/dir/my_dataset_cfg.yaml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(cfg, file)
```

4. Start the training process:

```
os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
trainer = CocoTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

I hope this helps you!